# CSS Animation moving back and forth with rotation

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a very simple animation move with CSS only.
What i'm trying to make is

Object moves back and forth between 200px and 800px, and as the object reaches the edges, it will rotate its direction.

```
.cow {
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    animation: cowmove 5s linear both infinite alternate,
                rotate 0.3s linear 5s; 

}

@keyframes cowmove{
    from{transform: translateX(200px);}
    to{transform: translateX(800px);}
}

@keyframes rotate{
    from{transform: rotateY(0);}
    to{transform: rotateY(180deg);}
}
```

This is what i've coded so far, but the rotate is hard for me.

with current code, the object will move from 200px to 800px, teleports to 200px point and rotate, teleports back to 800px point and move back to 200px.

It may be very simple solution, but i'm having a headache figuring this out :(

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating two `@keyframes`, you can do both transform in one like this:

```html
<div class="translate"></div> 

<style>
.translate{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #151f28;
  transition: 0.5s;
  animation: cowmove 4s infinite;                
} 
 
@keyframes cowmove{
    0% {
      transform: translateX(100px) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    49% {
      transform: translateX(500px) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    50% {
      transform: translateX(500px) rotateY(360deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(100px) rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it only one animation since you deal with the same property:

```css
.cow {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(blue 50%, red 0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  animation: cowmove 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes cowmove {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100px) rotate(0);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateX(400px) rotate(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(400px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(100px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100px) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cow"></div>
```

Comment: Oh come on.. Couldn't you wait 36 seconds more ? :)